# Cannot find name 'BrowserWindow'

Tags: javascript, angular, electron

In folder providers in electron.service.ts I have code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

// If you import a module but never use any of the imported values other than as TypeScript types,
// the resulting javascript file will look as if you never imported the module at all.
import { ipcRenderer, webFrame, remote, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';
import * as childProcess from 'child_process';
import * as fs from 'fs';

@Injectable()
export class ElectronService {

  ipcRenderer: typeof ipcRenderer;
  webFrame: typeof webFrame;
  remote: typeof remote;
  childProcess: typeof childProcess;
  win: BrowserWindow;
  fs: typeof fs;

  constructor() {
    // Conditional imports
    if (this.isElectron()) {
      this.ipcRenderer = window.require('electron').ipcRenderer;
      this.webFrame = window.require('electron').webFrame;
      this.remote = window.require('electron').remote;
      this.win = window.require('electron').remote.getCurrentWindow();

      this.childProcess = window.require('child_process');
      this.fs = window.require('fs');
    }
  }

  isElectron = () => {
    return window && window.process && window.process.type;
  }

}
```

In component I have method:

```
import { ElectronService } from '../../providers/electron.service';

toggleFullScreen() {
    const flag = !this.electron.win.isFullScreen();
    this.electron.win.show();
    this.electron.win.setFullScreen(flag);
    this.storeService.isFullScreen = this.electron.win.isFullScreen();
  }
```

When I write in my project

```
win: BrowserWindow;
```

I get error Cannot find name 'BrowserWindow'. What is wrong? I did 
import { ipcRenderer, webFrame, remote, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';
I can't rewrite instead

```
win: typeof BrowserWindow;
```

because in method toggleFullScreen() will not be to able method isFullScreen(), show(),setFullScreen().
App work good in develop mode, but I have error and I can't build exe file. How fix that?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I am familiar with

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
let win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
```

**Edit** : I have seen online where the type is specified as

```
win: Electron.BrowserWindow
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this code 
`win: Electron.BrowserWindow`
helped me, I haven't errors and I can build a exe file :)

Comment: Glad I could help.